# Implement a Blender-like pane UI with GTK+

Tags: user-interface, gtk, blender

I'm probably going to botch this explanation.

How could I implement a Blender-like user interface with GTK?  I don't mean the color schemes, I mean the drag-to-create-pane system.

In Blender, one can adjust pane size by dragging along the pane border (sort of like `GtkPaned`).  One can create a new pane by dragging on this grip icon in the corner.

[image: The icon]

And one can merge panes again by dragging on this same icon toward another pane.

The problem with using nested `GtkPaned` is that I wouldn't be able to merge some panes because of the nesting.

How would I do this otherwise?

**EDIT: Some pictures to clarify what I mean**

So here's the user interface. Note how it's split up into panes, and how each pane has a drag grip in the upper-right and lower-left.

[image: The user interface]

Dragging on one of the grips of a pane creates a new pane of the same type as that pane...

[image: Dragging]

And you can drag a grip on a pane toward another pane, in which an arrow will show up and on mouse release that other pane will be closed and this pane will take up the remaining space.

[image: Drag grip to close pane]

And this is pretty flexible, so you can do lots of different things like rearrange the entire interface...

[image]

My problem comes in the merging part.  Using nested `GtkPaned` might work if the two panes I am trying to merge are part of the same `GtkPaned`, but if they were of different `GtkPaned` it wouldn't work because I couldn't just check the position of the handle.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by panes. What panes are you looking for? Can you post a full screenshot of one (or showing what possibilities you want)?

Comment: @andlabs the blender widget referred to enables multiple editors to exist in the one window. It would compare to gimp, krita or photoshop where you can place dockable dialogs along the side of the window with multiple sections each containing multiple tabs. I would suggest looking at how gimp does it's dockable dialogs.

Comment: @andlabs I've added a few screenshots.  I'm sorry for my really horrible explanation.  If it still doesn't clarify things, you could download a copy of blender to see what I am trying to say, but I totally understand if you aren't going to make that much effort for my question.

Comment: GIMP doesn't do dockable windows, but you may want to look into [libgdl](https://developer.gnome.org/gdl/stable/), which provides similar functionality.